# Dask-ml load all data in memory RAM when it should load chunk by chunk

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dask

I have a problem when I train with **PartialSGDRegressor**, with dask-ml. It is supposed that if you train a model with **fit** method, dask-ml use an internal partial_fit inhereted from sklearn, but It seems it load all data from dataset in memory and it does not use the chunks to perform an incremental trainning.

Why does not perform an incremental trainning??

Memory report
[image]

Example:

```
import dask.array as da
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask_ml.linear_model
from dask.diagnostics import Profiler, ResourceProfiler, CacheProfiler

# path comes from: 
# http://www.nyc.gov/html/tlc/html/about/trip_record_data.shtml.

path = '...... csv'

df = dd.read_csv(ruta, parse_dates=['tpep_dropoff_datetime', 'tpep_pickup_datetime'], blocksize=25e6)
xd=x[['trip_distance','passenger_count','PULocationID','DOLocationID']].to_delayed()
xfull = [da.from_delayed(i, i.compute().shape, i.compute().dtypes) for i in xd]
xf = da.concatenate(xfull)

yd = x['fare_amount'].to_delayed()
yfull = [da.from_delayed(i, i.compute().shape, i.compute().dtypes) for i in yd]
yf = da.concatenate(yfull)

with Profiler() as prof, ResourceProfiler(dt=1) as rprof, CacheProfiler() as cprof:
   est = dask_ml.linear_model.PartialSGDRegressor(loss='squared_loss',penalty='l1',alpha=0.1,learning_rate='constant',eta0=0.000001,max_iter=10)

   est.fit(xf,yf)
```

This case happens when the csv takes up 35.3 GB
[image]

**If I make the pipeline myself it works correctly taken less than 5GB RAM**

Comment: Do you happen to have a reproducible example that maintainers could look at to recreate the same error?

Comment: I have the same problem with XGBoost, any help?